# Why are not appearing the next registrations in congresses?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a UserController that has the index() method that should get all the registrations in congresses by a user and for each registration get the congress details (title and date). So that is possible to show in the view "users.index" the congress title, date and registration date of all user registrations in congresses.

The congresses table has a column "end_congress_date", if the "end_congress_date" is still in past it means that the congress not end yet, otherwise it means that the congress already end..

But is not working, no results are appearing. Do you know why?

So I have the index() like:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $user = Auth::user();
        $registrations = $user->registrations()->with('congress')->get();
        return view('users.index', compact('user','registrations'));
    }
}
```

The "`dd($registrations);`" shows:

```
Collection {#281 ▼
  #items: array:17 [▼
    0 => Registration {#287 ▶}
    1 => Registration {#288 ▶}
    2 => Registration {#289 ▶}
  ]
}
```

index.blade.php:

```
 <ul class="list-group congresses-list" id="">
        @foreach($registrations->where('congress_end_date', '<=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()) as $reg)
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <p class="font-size-sm"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    {{$reg->congress->congress_start_date->formatLocalized('%a, %b %d, %Y - %H:%M')}}</p>
                <h5 class="card-title">{{$reg->congress->name}}</h5>
                <p> Registration done in {{$reg->created_at}}</p>
            </li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
```

Comment: Was the `dd` command in the view or the controller? Does the view actually receive the `$registrations` variable? Are you sure that there are actually values that match the `where` statement in your database?

Comment: In the UserController, I dont know if the issue is because the congress_end_date is in the table "congresses" not in registrations table".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend adding one or two helper methods on the `Congress` model which tell you whether a congress has ended already or not. I expect knowing this is a common requirement throughout your application.

```
class Congress
{
    // other code

    public function isFinished(): bool
    {
        return $this->congress_end_date < now();
    }
}
```

(This expects you to have a `$dates = ['congress_end_date', ...]` cast on the model.)

You can then use the `filter()` method on your collection to retrieve all `Registrations` with a `Congress` that is finished already (or also the opposite):

```
@foreach($registrations->filter(function ($item) { return $item->congress->isFinished(); }) as $reg)
    // do something with the registrations of finished congresses
@endforeach
```

---

**[optional: only if you do not need all registrations, but only the finished ones]**

If you do not plan on using all the items in `$registrations`, but only the ones with a finished congress, I would recommend that you only fetch those you need. You can do this in your controller by swapping

```
$registrations = $user->registrations()->with('congress')->get();
```

in favour of

```
$registrations = $user->registrations()
    ->with('congress')
    ->whereHas(['congress' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('congress_end_date', '<', now());
    }])
    ->get();
```

You can then simply iterate through them in your view without filtering before:

```
@foreach($registrations as $reg)
    // ...
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to have in the same page two tabs, one tab "Past congresses" when is clicekd shows the div with the past congresses, another tab "Next congresses" that when is clicked it shows the div with the "next congresses". So it should be necessary to return all the registrations in congresses of the user no?

Comment: Yes, in this case you should only use the first part of the answer. I added a divider to my answer to make clear that the second part is optional.

Comment: Thanks, it appaers "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::isFinished() " with "                                        @foreach($registrations->filter(function ($item) { return $item->isFinished(); }) as $reg)
", Do you know why?

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, it should be `$item->congress->isFinished()`. Corrected in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but is appearing "Call to a member function pastCongresses() on null". Do you know why? I change isFinished() with pastCongresses() and notFinished() with nextCongresses().

Comment: Like:  public function nextCongresses(): bool
    {
        return $this->congress_end_date < now();
    }

    public function pastCongresses(): bool
    {
        return $this->congress_end_date > now();
    }

Comment: Yeah, that is because there is `Registrations` in your list that do not have a `Congress` assigned. You can use `$registrations = $user->registrations()->has('congress')->with('congress')->get();` in your controller to only fetch registrations that have a congress.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are attempting a loop on something that doesn't exist:

```
@foreach($registrations->where('congress_end_date', '<=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()) as $reg)
```

The `congress_end_date` field doesn't exist on the **registration** object, it exists on the relationship: congress.  So, the if-check (if the date is less than now) will fail 100% of the time.  Thus... no registrations will show up on the users.index page.

You have a few options, you can pull from the DB by congress (assuming you have the relationship back to registrations), or maybe easiest would be to loop on $registrations like you have, but remove the date check from the foreach loop and add an if check on the congress model below.  Something like this (assuming the congress relation is not many to many):

```
@foreach($registrations as $registration)
    if($registration->congress->congress_end_date < \Carbon\Carbon::now()))
        // do what you want with the congress model that hasn't ended yet here
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Test it by doing a {{dd($registrations)}} on the blade page.  Look at the congress relationship in the dump.  Look at the value of congress_end_date.  Is it possible that none are earlier than now?  If so, that would fail the if-check.  If there are no congress relations on any items, that is also a possibility where there may not be any in the database.  The code above will show what you are looking for if the original pull from the DB yielded any results.

Comment: Thanks, the "{{$registrations}}
" it appears like "[{"id":1,"status":"C","congress_id":1,"main_participant_id":1,,"congress":{"id":1,"name":"test","description":"","congress_start_date":"2018-05-08 06:30:00","congress_end_date":"2018-05-08 15:30:00",....}},".